# Mockito tests work separately but when run together only one works

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I have been encountering a strange issue. My test cases have two failing tests, first and third. However, if I run the same separetely, it runs perfectly. I am new to JUnit and have no idea why this could happen. I tried to resed mocks and initialize them in setUp() method, but it didn't help.
Is there any problems with static cache?

````
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class CharCounterTest {

    private CharCounter charCounter;
    private CharCounter spyCharCounter;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        charCounter = new CharCounter();
        spyCharCounter = Mockito.spy(charCounter);
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void cleanUp(){
        Mockito.reset(spyCharCounter);
    }

    @Test
    void given3IdenticalInputs_whenGetCharacterFrequency_thenPutInputInCacheOnce() {
        //CharCounter charCounter = Mockito.spy(new CharCounter());
        spyCharCounter.getCharacterFrequency("hello world!");
        spyCharCounter.getCharacterFrequency("hello world!");
        spyCharCounter.getCharacterFrequency("hello world!");

        Mockito.verify(spyCharCounter, Mockito.times(1)).countCharacters("hello world!");
    }

    @Test
    void given3DiffrentsInputs_whenGetCharacterFrequency_thenPutInputInCacheThrice() {
        //CharCounter charCounter = Mockito.spy(new CharCounter());
        spyCharCounter.getCharacterFrequency("hello world!");
        spyCharCounter.getCharacterFrequency("hello!");
        spyCharCounter.getCharacterFrequency("world!");

        Mockito.verify(spyCharCounter, Mockito.times(1)).countCharacters("hello world!");
        Mockito.verify(spyCharCounter, Mockito.times(1)).countCharacters("hello!");
        Mockito.verify(spyCharCounter, Mockito.times(1)).countCharacters("world!");
    }

    @Test
    void given2IdenticalAnd1DiffrentInputs_whenGetCharacterFrequency_thenPutInputInCacheTwice() {
        //CharCounter charCounter = Mockito.spy(new CharCounter());
        spyCharCounter.getCharacterFrequency("hello world!");
        spyCharCounter.getCharacterFrequency("hello world!");
        spyCharCounter.getCharacterFrequency("world!");

        Mockito.verify(spyCharCounter, Mockito.times(1)).countCharacters("hello world!");
        Mockito.verify(spyCharCounter, Mockito.times(1)).countCharacters("world!");
    }
}```

/*There's a CharCounter class, maybe there is some problems with static cache?
*/

```public class CharCounter {

    private static final CacheDecorator cache = new CacheDecorator(new LinkedHashMap<>());

    public Map<String, Long> getCharacterFrequency(String text) {

        Map<String, Long> characterFrequency;
        if (cache.containsKey(text)) {
            characterFrequency = cache.getData(text);
        } else {
            characterFrequency = countCharacters(text);
            cache.putData(text, characterFrequency);
        }
        return characterFrequency;
    }

    public Map<String, Long> countCharacters(String text) {
        Map<String, Long> frequencies = Arrays.stream(text.split(""))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
        return frequencies;
    }
}```
````

Comment: How does CharCounter keep the cache internally? If it's a **static cache**, the tests will have side-effects.

Comment: Yeah, it's have static cache, i added the code.

Comment: if it's static, it's not going to reset when you call the constructor of "CharCounter". you need to reset it directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in the static cache, if you write tests this way, it will work

```
@Test
    void given3IdenticalInputs_whenGetCharacterFrequency_thenPutInputInCacheOnce() {
        spyCharCounter.getCharacterFrequency("hello world!");
        spyCharCounter.getCharacterFrequency("hello world!");
        spyCharCounter.getCharacterFrequency("hello world!");

        Mockito.verify(spyCharCounter, Mockito.times(1)).countCharacters("hello world!");
    }

    @Test
    void given3DiffrentsInputs_whenGetCharacterFrequency_thenPutInputInCacheThrice() {
        spyCharCounter.getCharacterFrequency("my name is!");
        spyCharCounter.getCharacterFrequency("my!");
        spyCharCounter.getCharacterFrequency("name!");

        Mockito.verify(spyCharCounter, Mockito.times(1)).countCharacters("my name is!");
        Mockito.verify(spyCharCounter, Mockito.times(1)).countCharacters("my!");
        Mockito.verify(spyCharCounter, Mockito.times(1)).countCharacters("name!");
    }

    @Test
    void 
 given2IdenticalAnd1DiffrentInputs_whenGetCharacterFrequency_thenPutInputInCacheTwice() {
        spyCharCounter.getCharacterFrequency("something!");
        spyCharCounter.getCharacterFrequency("something!");
        spyCharCounter.getCharacterFrequency("problem!");

        Mockito.verify(spyCharCounter, Mockito.times(1)).countCharacters("something!");
        Mockito.verify(spyCharCounter, Mockito.times(1)).countCharacters("problem!");
    }
```